# Refresh TextView on return from Activity

Tags: android, textview, refresh, preferenceactivity, preference

I'm writing a small application which saves your preferences. In the main activity, these preferences should be displayed. However, When returning from the PreferenceActivity Class, I still get the old values. The view only gets updated once I actually quit the app via the "Back" Button.

I've tried putting the setText command in the onResume() and onRestoreInstanceState() functions, but none actually refresh it.

What do I have to do to get it to refresh?

Comment: Have you checked whether the preferences value passed in onResume method are the recent one or older one. Please paste the code of your activity so one can get understand the issue correctly .

Comment: Yeah that was actually the issue...thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud override onSharedPreferenceChanged to react to changed preference:

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,String key) {
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If PreferenceActivity is directly called from your main activity, a solution would be to start PreferenceActivity with the method startActivityForResult. This method allows to pass back some data from the activity which is launched to the activity which launched it.
This means you will have to implement in your main activity the method onActivityResult.

If you choose this solution, check the article "Getting a Result from an Activity" on the official doc : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html